# How to display national characters in a Windows desktop app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, character-encoding

A Windows C++ desktop application displays texts with Swedish national characters. I develop it in Visual Studio (VS), as a "C++ Windows Desktop" project. VS builds a basic application with many files: one .`cpp` file, two .`ico` files, three .`h` files, one .`rc` file, and some project files, so it is too much to present here, and I'm showing only the important parts.

In `wWinMain`, I added a console to display texts using `cout`.

```
AllocConsole();
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
FILE* stream;
freopen_s(&stream, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
```

I am trying several ways to display text in `WndProc` in response to the `WM_PAINT` signal.

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        RECT rec;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rec);

        if (FIRST)
        {
            FIRST = false;
            // Test with const char* s
            const char* t1 = "Test 1:   const char* s";
            DrawTextA(hdc, (LPCSTR)t1, (int)strlen(t1), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            cout << t1 << endl;
            rec.top += 16;
            const char* s = "abcdef ååääöö ÅÅÄÄÖÖ\n";
            DrawTextA(hdc, (LPCSTR)s, (int)strlen(s), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            cout << s << endl;
            rec.top += 16;

            // Test with string text 
            const char* t2 = "Test 2   string text";
            DrawTextA(hdc, (LPCSTR)t2, (int)strlen(t2), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            cout << t2 << endl;
            rec.top += 16;
            string text = "abcdef ååääöö ÅÅÄÄÖÖ\n";
            DrawTextA(hdc, (LPCSTR)&text, (int)text.length(), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            cout << text << endl;
            rec.top += 16;

            // Test with text (const char*) & string
            const char* t3 = "Test 3   (const char*)& \"..\"";
            DrawTextA(hdc, (LPCSTR)t3, (int)strlen(t3), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            cout << t3 << endl;
            rec.top += 16;
            text = "abcdef ååääöö ÅÅÄÄÖÖ\n";
            const char* t = (const char*)&text;
            DrawTextA(hdc, (LPCSTR)t, (int)strlen(t), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            cout << t << endl;;
            rec.top += 16;

            // Test with wide string text 
            const char* t4 = "Test 4   wstring text";
            DrawTextA(hdc, (LPCSTR)t4, (int)strlen(t4), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            cout << t4 << endl;
            rec.top += 16;
            wstring wtext = L"abcdef ååääöö ÅÅÄÄÖÖ\n";
            DrawTextW(hdc, (LPCWSTR)&wtext, (int)wtext.length(), &rec, DT_TOP | DT_LEFT);
            wcout << wtext << endl;
            rec.top += 16;
        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

The meaning of this is to verify how national characters are displayed using text sources in `const char*`, `string`, `wstring`, and `const char*` created from a `string`. The output in the desktop client window and in the console is presented below.

[image]

[image]

The output is correct when `DrawTextA` displays text as `const char*`. However, the displayed text is distorted when `DrawTextA` shows text from a `string` or `const char*` created from a `string`. Also, using `wstring` didn't help.

In my application, I must be able to display texts kept in `string`s. I don't care much about the console output; it is only there to make the testing easier. What am I missing?

Comment: [There's No Such Thing As Plain Text](https://youtu.be/hI-eAg3hlcM). Once you've internalized that, the solution will automagically unfold, or rather, the set of two possible solutions out of all possible approaches.

Comment: Also, every cast is a lie. It's the tool you use to convince the compiler that something that isn't right is actually OK. You've fooled the compiler into trusting you, both when trust is justifiable but also when it isn't (e.g. `(LPCSTR)&text` which needs to be `text.c_str()` instead).

Comment: I've tried it, and it works. In fact, it solves my problem; thank you for this rapid solution. I suggest you make it the answer. Perhaps you could add some explanation. I don't know why tests 3 and 4 fail. Maybe you see a flaw there as well.

Comment: Tests 3 and 4 fail for the same reason. It's those `trust_me_i_m_a_trained_professional<>` casts, disguised as innocuous C-style casts, that nudge the compiler from *"This cannot be right"* into *"You know, that sounds like a good idea"* mode. The only difference literally is the point upon which the compiler cheerfully assists you in exploring the vast space that is UB.

Comment: The reason 2, 3 and 4 don't work is actually nothing to do with national characters, and everything to do with lying about what kind of string it is. E.g. in test 2, you say "please draw this many characters" but then the pointer doesn't point to that many characters, it points to a `std::string` (which contains a pointer to a string but is not actually a string itself)

Comment: @user253751: Correct. In all the three cases casting was used instead of c_str(). You can always learn new things.